# AttributeError: 'TestimonyForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django

Help needed. I have no idea what is error-ed in the line of code. The traceback points to the form.save() line.

```
#views.py
class TestimonyFormFunction(View):
    form = TestimonyForm 
    template = 'variablized_form.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TestimonyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'testimony_post.html', {'Testimony':Testimony})



            else:
                form = TestimonyForm()
                return render(request, 'variablized_form.html', {'form': form})


#forms.py
class TestimonyForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label='Details', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: Please share the `TestimonyForm` class. Is this a `ModelForm`?

Comment: Just shared. Do let me know if something catches your eye.

Comment: It is not a `ModelForm`, "simple" `Form`s have no `.save()` method.

Comment: To what model is your `TestimonyForm` supposed to save data? Besides models (and files), there are not much *persistent* structures supported by Django (well there are some extra apps that allow to add extra possibilities), but a `Form` itself can not save the data.

Comment: I am saving it to my model named Testimony. I think given the information you guys gave i would be better off just changing the form into a model form. Thank you for the information.